# Converting a regex Apache mod_rewrite RewriteCond to Nginx

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, nginx

Here's my Apache .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # rewrite /{bookVerb}/{qs} to /book/{qs}
    RewriteCond $1 ^((book|reservar|reserver|buchen|riservare)($|\/.*)) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /book/%2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I use that on an nginx server?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following rule inside your `server { }` block

```
if ($request_uri ~* ^/en/(?:book|reservar|reserver|buchen|riservare)(?:/(.*))?$) {
    rewrite ^ /book/$1 break;
}
```

I'm assuming you want to capture and pass what comes after `/reservar/..` etc. In your original rule, `%2` is actually capturing the `{bookVerb}`, not `{qs}`.

Comment: Thanks. My original post was slightly incorrect in that the full URL has a local string preceeding it (en/book, es/reservar, etc). So the suggestion fails. I tried amending to ^/(?:en\/book| etc... but I get an internal server error.

Comment: Change it to `^/en/(...`. Forward slashes in regexs usually do not need to be escaped (unless it's like JavaScript).

Comment: That would work only for /en/book and /en/reservar rather than /es/reservar, however I get an internal server error on the /en one, so I think there is a problem with the code there?

Comment: Just for testing if you use `~* (abc)$` does `en/abc` and `es/abc` go to `book/abc`? This will check if nginx is setup for rewriting or not.